# Button placement next to Input field with Mantine React

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I am trying to place a button next to an input field in react using the Mantine library. My input field looks like this (with styling):

```
const useStyles = createStyles((theme, { opened }: { opened: boolean }) => ({
  control: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: `${theme.spacing.xs} ${theme.spacing.md}`,
    borderRadius: theme.radius.md,
    border: `${rem(1)} solid ${
      theme.colorScheme === "dark" ? theme.colors.dark[6] : theme.colors.gray[2]
    }`,
    transition: "background-color 150ms ease",
  },

  label: {
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: theme.fontSizes.sm,
  },

  icon: {
    transition: "transform 150ms ease",
    transform: opened ? "rotate(180deg)" : "rotate(0deg)",
  },
}));
```

And the component itself is given as:

```
//general input field, takes any string
export const ApprovalStatus: React.FC<GenericInputFormProps> = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  index,
}) => {
  ... # retrieving data etc.
  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
            // dropdownComponent={}
            maxDropdownHeight="280px"
            label={label}
            limit={20}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            className={classes.control}
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue}
            data={flatData}
          />
    </>
  );
};
```

This creates the following component:

[Example of created input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abA8Z.png)

Now, I would like to add a small button right of the description to explain more in depth what the input field expects.

I tried to do that using the `Popover` function from Mantine:

```
 return (
    <>
      <Popover width={200} position="top" withArrow shadow="md">
        <Popover.Target>
          <ActionIcon variant="filled">
            <IconQuestionMark size="1.125rem"/>
          </ActionIcon>
        </Popover.Target>
        <Popover.Dropdown>
          <Text size="sm">
            Test popover
          </Text>
        </Popover.Dropdown>
      </Popover>
      <Autocomplete
            // dropdownComponent={}
            maxDropdownHeight="280px"
            label={label}
            limit={20}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            className={classes.control}
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue}
            data={flatData}
          />
    </>
  );
};
```

The result, however, is as follows:

[Button added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iln2H.png)

As you can see the button comes, logically so, above the input field. Does anyone have any idea how I can style the button such that it appears left of the input field, within the borders? Any help is appreciated. Everything is done in React using the Mantine library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `styles` or `classNames` attribute from `<Autocomplete />` to modify your design as per your liking.

```
import {
  Autocomplete,
  ActionIcon,
} from '@mantine/core';

<Autocomplete
  data={['React', 'Angular', 'Svelte', 'Vue']}
  rightSection={<ActionIcon onClick={console.log}>A</ActionIcon>}
/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make the button actionable, and it puts the icon inside the input field. I would like the button to be outside the input field. Is that possible to achieve using styles? or maybe using the styles API

Comment: @anonymousbird Ah, I see. I've updated the code now, to make use of `rightSection` prop instead of `icon` which does indeed take in user action. No other change is required.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. I sometimes have trouble making sense of the component props as I am still new to React and TS. One final question: Do you know if it is at all possible to move props like this outside of the Autocomplete component at all?

Comment: Actually. I think I got it by using styling on the rightSection. The solution is a bit makeshift but it works :)